# Django: nested template commands

Tags: django, templates

I am following the tutorial of [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/). When I came to this part of writing nested block template commands in `about.html`:

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
{% block title %}About{% endblock %}

{% block bodyBlock %}
  <img src="{% static '/rango/images/pythonDjango.jpg' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

The system complains with the error message: `Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'`

How should the above nested commands be arranged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` tag is not loaded into the template. So, at the top of the template, add:

```
{% load static %}
```

Everything else with the posted template looks fine.